# How to connect to docker-compose postgres database using sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I have this docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  # MongoDB service: Used for storing and managing MongoDB databases.
  database:
    image: mongo:5.0.17
    container_name: db_cont
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}  # MongoDB root user username
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}  # MongoDB root user password
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE}  # MongoDB root database name
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'  # Port mapping: Host port -> Container port
    volumes:
      - db_vols:/data/db  # Persistent volume for MongoDB data # Persistent volume for MongoDB data
    networks:
      - compose_network

  # PostgreSQL service: Used for storing and managing PostgreSQL databases.
  datawarehouse:
    image: postgres:15.3
    restart: always
    container_name: dw_cont
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}  # PostgreSQL superuser username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}  # PostgreSQL superuser password
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}  # Default PostgreSQL database name
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'  # Port mapping: Host port -> Container port
    volumes:
      - dw_vols:/var/lib/postgresql/data  # Persistent volume for PostgreSQL data
    networks:
      - compose_network

  # Prefect service: Runs the Prefect server for workflow management.
  prefect:
    image: prefecthq/prefect:2-python3.10
    container_name: prefect_cont
    entrypoint: ["prefect", "server", "start"]
    environment:
      - PREFECT_API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:4300/api/
      - PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - PREFECT_ORION_DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL=postgresql+asyncpg://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@datawarehouse:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}  # Connection URL for the Prefect server to connect to PostgreSQL
    ports:
      - '4300:4200'  # Port mapping: Host port -> Container port
    volumes:
      - prefect_vols:/data/prefect  # Persistent volume for Prefect server data
    depends_on:
      - datawarehouse  # Ensure PostgreSQL is running before starting Prefect
    networks:
      - compose_network
      
  # PgAdmin service: Web-based administration tool for PostgreSQL.
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:7.4
    container_name: pgadmin
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL} #pgadmin email
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD} #pgadmin password
    ports:
      - '5050:80' # Port mapping: Host port -> Container port
    depends_on:
      - datawarehouse # Ensure PostgreSQL is running before starting PgAdmin
    networks:
      - compose_network
  #Service to manage requirements.txt
  requirements:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: requirements_cont
    ports: 
      - '8000:8000' #Port mapping: host port --> container port
    networks:
      - compose_network
    command: sh -c "tail -f /dev/null && pre-commit install"
volumes:
  db_vols:  # Volume for MongoDB data
  dw_vols:  # Volume for PostgreSQL data
  prefect_vols:  # Volume for Prefect server data

networks:
  compose_network:
    driver: bridge
```

I am trying to connect to the postgresql after the container is running using sqlalchemy (I used test as my user, password, and db_name):

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text, Numeric, Date, TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


engine = create_engine("postgresql://test:test@datawarehouse/test")

Session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

BaseModel = declarative_base()
```

But I keep getting this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "datawarehouse" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Anyone able to help? Is it because I am writing this python file outside of the docker container? I

Comment: try `postgresql://test:test@localhost/test` -- if you are running the python code from the host machine (not from within a container), you will need to use the exposed port (`5432`) to connect into the container

Comment: @richyen thanks for the suggestion - I now got this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "test" does not exist

which does not make sense as I create the role test with the POSTGRES_USER env variable in the docker-compose

Comment: It seems you already have a postgres instance running on your local machine, so the docker container can't publish the 5432 port.  You can shut down postgres on your machine (or use a different port on your `docker-compose.yml`, like `5444:5432`, then in your `create_engine()` call, use `postgresql://test:test@localhost:5444/test`

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "datawarehouse" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

`datawarehouse` is the name on your docker compose network. To access it
locally, you need to use "localhost" instead.

Here's an example to set up a Docker container running PostgreSQL 15, and how to
connect to it:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
    postgres15:
        image: postgres:15
        container_name: postgres15
        restart: "unless-stopped"
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=test_user
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test_password
            - POSTGRES_DB=test
            - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--encoding=UTF8"
        networks:
            - docker_compose

networks:
    docker_compose:
```

```py
from sqlalchemy import String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, sessionmaker


engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg2://test_user:test_password@localhost:5432/test",
    echo=True,
)

Session = sessionmaker(
    bind=engine,
)


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "test"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    data: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```